# Unique index on multiple columns vs single column index

Tags: index, performance, psql, query-performance

I have a table in the following structure. Now from a data integrity standpoint I want to add a joint uniqueness index on `product_id` and `item_id`. Now there can be around 100K `product_id` and 50k `item_id`. Generally my queries would like `Select item_id from product_items where product_id = 'some-id' and item_type=2`. Will the uniqueness index be sufficient in this case or should i add a separate index on `product_id` as well. Also does uniqueness order matter when creating unique index

```
     product_items
      :id, 
      :product_id
      :item_id
      :item_type (int)
      :created_at
      :updated_at
```

Comment: What is the DBMS? Postgres?

Comment: The uniqueness index should be sufficient for your needs (no need to create a completely separate index structure).  And the order specified on the index always matters, in this case you probably want product_id and item_type to be the first two items.

Answer (score 4):

Since your DBMS isn't specified, I'll respond in general terms.

Assuming your uniqueness index specifies `product_id` as the first column and `item_id` as the second, the index can be used either to locate a specific row based on `product_id` and `item_id`, or all rows with a given `product_id`.

An index can be used to speed searches when the query uses the first column defined as part of the index, and will locate rows based on the first *n* columns in the index if the `WHERE` clause (or `JOIN` conditions) use all of the first *n* rows.

So, if `product_id` is the first column listed in the index's creation, then it could be used any time you're locating records based on `product_id`. The index would *not* be used for `SELECT product_id FROM product_items where item_id = 'some-id' and created_at > '2018-01-01'`, because `item_id` isn't the first column in the unique index.

NOTE: Your unique (non-clustered) index might well be scanned if the query was `SELECT product_id FROM product_items WHERE item_id = 'some-id'`, because it would be a *covering index*. Since all the columns needed be the query exist in the index, the DB engine may be able to treat the index as if it were the `product_items` table itself, allowing it to just read the index, instead of the entire table and the full data rows. (If the unique index is also `product_items`'s clustered index, then the index *is* the table).